# Play iframe video on click of link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i would like a youtube video pop up to open when the user clicks a particular link on my webpage. I have tried and tried to work this out but have really struggled. I'm sure this is achievable through JQuery but i'm not sure.

HTML is

```
<div class="audiodemo">
<div class="audiodemoheader"> “Welcome to the Recovery Show, who's on   board?”</div>
<div class="audiodemolink"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kh29_SERH0Y?  rel=0" rel="prettyPhoto" class="demolink">Listen</a></div>
```

CSS is

```
.audiodemo {
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
float: left;
background-image: url(../images/hero.jpg);
}

.audiodemoheader {
width:100%;
height:auto;
text-align:center;
float:left;
margin-top:94.5px;
font: 200 18px/1.3 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI Light', sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 200;
color: #FFF;

}

.audiodemolink {
width:100%;
height:auto;
text-align:center;
float:left;
margin-top:40px;


}


.audiodemolink .demolink {
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 11px 51px;
border: 3px solid #fff;
-webkit-transition: .2s;
transition: .2s;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

.audiodemolink .demolink:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend using a jquery plugin such as this: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: @pptaszek1990 thank you. I'm not particularly familiar with that could you help further?

Comment: You could also use modal in the Bootstrap framework if you already have some Bootstrap styling on your site: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples  (see "Live demo")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bootstrap:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nqnmc9cn/1/)

*HTML*

```
<div class="audiodemo">
    <div class="audiodemoheader">“Welcome to the Recovery Show, who's on board?”</div>
    <div class="audiodemolink">
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kh29_SERH0Y" rel="prettyPhoto" class="demolink">Listen</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            ...
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
jQuery('.demolink').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var youtubeLink = $(this).attr('href').replace('watch?v=','embed/');
    var html = '<iframe width="620" height="320" src="'+ youtubeLink +'?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $('.modal-body').html(html);
    $('#myModal').modal().on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
        $('.modal-body').html('');    
    })             
});
```

and bootstrap files:

http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Magnific Popup to achieve this. The first thing would be to include the necessary files. I got this from the documentation page: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

```
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css"> 

<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
```

Once you have those included you need to write a jQuery function to call the plugin. I got the below function from one of their examples but you can update it with options that fit what you want to accomplish.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-youtube').magnificPopup({
        disableOn: 700,
        type: 'iframe',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: false,
        fixedContentPos: false
    });
});
```

The last thing you need to do is call it in your html.

```
<a class="popup-youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O2aH4XLbto">Open YouTube video</a>
```

You can style it as you wish. If you would like to see some more examples you can take a look at the [documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) as it explains everything pretty clearly.